# adding an div in autosuggest

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am implementing the [bsn autosuggest](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html)

can any one tellme how can i add an div in the result the result will be formed like this

```
<div style="left: 347px; top: 1024px; width: 400px;" class="autosuggest" id="as_testinput_xml">
    <div class="as_header">
        <div class="as_corner"></div>
        <div class="as_bar"></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="as_ul">
        <li>
            <a name="1" href="#">
            <span class="tl"> </span>
            <span class="tr"> </span>
            <span><em>W</em>aldron, Ashley<br><small>Leicestershire</small></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a name="2" href="#">
            <span class="tl"> </span>
            <span class="tr"> </span>
            <span><em>W</em>heeler, Bysshe<br><small>Lincolnshire</small></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="as_footer">
        <div class="as_corner"></div>
        <div class="as_bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to add an diva above the ul as the Category like

```
<div>Category</div>
```

i tried

```
var tmp = _bsn.DOM.createElement("div", {className:"tmp"});
```

and i need to know how to add values to the div using java script .....

Answer (score 0):

This autocomplete system hasn't been updated since 2007.  I think it'd be wise for you to try something that's more up to date.  Do you use jQuery?  This is what I'd recommend: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete, it handles all the work for you.

An advantage with using jQuery is that you can utilize Google's CDN: http://css-tricks.com/google-cdn-naming/

There's a very high chance your visitor won't have to download jQuery cause it's already been used on another site.